# iOS categories, subclass and override

Tags: ios, overriding, subclass, categories

when I build my project I have this warning:

```
ld: warning: instance method 'shareMessage' in category from /Users/attiliopatania/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Objects-normal/armv7/Place+Factory.o conflicts with same method from another category
```

I'm not be able to understand where is the issue with the structure I report to you, maybe I make a mistake on using the categories
This issue born when I force myself to use the pattern of @class declaratin on .h file and #import of the useful headers class witinh the .m
I hope that somebody can help me :)

*shareMessage* is a method declared within the class Bean.h that is parent for Place+Factory in this way:

Place+Factory.h

```
#import "Place.h"

@interface Place (Factory)
...
@end
```

Place+Factory.m

```
#import "Place+Factory.h"
#import "User+Factory.h"


@implementation Place (Factory)

...

- (NSString*) shareMessage{
     return @"myMessage"
}


...
@end
```

NB: User+Factory have the same structure of PlaceFactory and it is a child of Bean too.

Place.h

```
#import "Bean.h"

@interface Place : Bean
...


@end
```

Bean.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HttpFunction.h"
#import "Usefull.h"
#import "AppManager.h"


@interface Bean : NSObject
...
- (NSString*) shareMessage;


@end
```

Bean.m

```
#import "Bean.h"

@implementation Bean 

...

- (NSString*) shareMessage{
    return [self.class description];

}

...
@end
```

**updated**:
at the end I **solved**. I review all my classes handling where possibile @ class within the .h files and the # **import order** within the .m files (that it seems to be the real issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because class Place already has method shareMessage, it inherits this method from Bean. 
    @implementation Bean (Factory)  change to @implementation Bean

Comment: do you mean @ implementation Place(Factory) -> @ implementation Bean within the Place+Factory.h?